# Howto selenium testing infratstructure with python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-rc

Any suggestions on how to setup a selenium testing environment using python. I know question is vague but for being the standard for web front end testing selenium does not want to seem to work, a useful tutorial would be fine.

My current dev environment is setup like this:

- Checked out code: /home/workspace/trunk
- Python Path: /var/python
- Then I have a Repo Server, Dev Server and Prod Server

I would like to be able to easily switch between basically bleeding edge, beta, and production

Where should I be putting my selenium? Firefox Profile? this stuff has been confusing me forever on how to properly set it up.

Comment: I would suggest you to have a look at [Splinter](http://splinter.cobrateam.info/). It adds a layer above Selenium which makes the process of running and writing tests easer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using Selenium 2 (AKA webdriver), and you *should* because it's awesome, it will create a new, temporary, profile for you and install the extension is uses to drive the browser.  So just [write your test suite](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/unittest.html#basic-example) and [create your driver instance](http://seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.html#id4) in your test and use it.